# Both AutoCAD 2007 & 2014 on a Win 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, autocad

Is it possible to install both AutoCAD 2007 & AutoCAD 2014 on a Win 7 x64 ultimate machine? If yes, how to install them? Which one should be installed first please?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try? What makes you think you can / can't? What does your own research suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install both, just give it a go!

Install them both the normal way, they will be fine side by side!